# two way data binding in this case does not assign an empty value AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have function which answer for pushing items into array. On end function I assign empty string to $scope.newTask for clearing value inside **textarea**.

But...

Problem is that it not working, after execute function, value inside textarea still is. Could someone explain me why?

**HTML**

```
<form name="cardFrm" novalidate>
  <textarea ng-model="newTask" ng-keypress="($event.keyCode==13) ? addTask(newTask, $index) : return"></textarea>
  <button ng-click="addTask(newTask, $index)">Add</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.addTask = (newTask, index) => { 
    $scope.board.lists[index].cards.push({ 'name': newTask, 'deadline': null, members: [] });
    $scope.newTask = '';

};
```

Comment: did you check the console after inspect is your **$scope.board.lists[index].cards.push({ 'name': newTask, 'deadline': null, members: [] });** executing? according to me if this statement itself doesn't execute then only the $scope.newTask='' wont reflect on ui. Please check the same.

Comment: Yes is working cards.push but not $scope.newTask clearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is a nested scope. Check in the addTask method if $scope.newTask is equals to newTask received as first parameter. To resolve this problem you can use a controllerAs syntax or save a value in a complex object, for example:

**HTML**

```html
<form name="cardFrm" novalidate>
  <textarea ng-model="obj.newTask" ng-keypress="($event.keyCode==13) ? addTask(obj.newTask, $index) : return">   </textarea>
  <button ng-click="addTask(obj.newTask, $index)">Add</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```js
$scope.obj.newTask  = '';

$scope.addTask = (newTask, index) => { 
    $scope.board.lists[index].cards.push({ 'name': newTask, 'deadline': null, members: [] });
    $scope.obj.newTask = '';

};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working fiddle to push items into an array and clear the textbox:

```
$scope.cards = [];

$scope.addTask = (newTask, index) => {
  $scope.cards.push({
    'name': newTask
  });
  $scope.newTask = '';
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/junkangli/pL2wrted/

The problem with your code should be the statement:

`$scope.board.lists[index].cards.push({ 'name': newTask, 'deadline': null, members: [] });`

Comment: I dont understand, what should I to fix that??